# Network login, windows 8.1

Tags: wireless-networking, security

Windows 8.1 won't give option to connect to wifi securely

Can 8.1 only be connected by using an 8 digit pin? I can't find any other way to do this.

I have heard that 8.1 has eliminated WPA, so maybe the pin automatically does WPA2? TOTALLY unclear!!! But it seems that WPA2 should have a longer entry than 8 digits!?!

I REALLY want to use WPA2, but this option cannot be specifically found. It just asks for the PIN.

Please give very clear step by step instructions, as NOTHING about this is clear or obvious.

One of the routers used with this computer has 2 different numbers on itfor various levels of security :
1) WPS PIN (used on this 8.1 computer)
2) WPA2 Key (can't find a way to use this)

Does 8.1 uses the PIN for WPA2, which doesn't seem to match normal processes? AND other devices with a secure connection require the WPA2?!?

Comment: OK, then how do I force the use of WPA2?  I can find NO way at present, except the use of the 8 digit PIN number.

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows 8.1 only eliminated TKIP encryption. All of the other items are still supported. So you can setup your WiFi AP using WPA2 personal with AES or WPA2 Enterprise with TLS or MSCHAP

Comment: So the 8 digit pin connects through WPA2?

This situation is REALLY unclear - why use a wimpy 8 character identifier on a strong connection type?  And NOT say what type of connection it is?

Is there a way to check the security type of this connection?  How can I make sure what type of connection I have?